# Redundant characters in string, c

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to get selected characters from one string into another. Everything looks okay, except the program keeps adding additional characters to the output. And it seems that it tends to add different number of these "unecessary" characters. Where might the problem be?

```
int main(void) {
    int i,j=0;
    char string[256];
    char second_arr[256];
    scanf("%255s", string);

    for(i=0;i<256;i++){
        if(string[i]=='('||string[i]=='['||string[i]=='{'){
            second_arr[j]=string[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", second_arr);
}
```

Say,

```
input: (hello)(}[} --->
Output:(([[H
```

Comment: Right off the top of my head, I'm pretty sure your problem is a buffer overrun. Your for loop is moving past the end of the string you add in, and it's taking stuff from memory which hasn't been initialized.

Comment: To copy the terminator you can include it in the `if` test: `if(string[i]=='('||string[i]=='['||string[i]=='{'||string[i]==0)`

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: You're not testing `scanf` for failure. It can return `EOF`, or zero to indicate the input didn't match your format string.

Problem 2: You're copying all 256 chars even if the user entered fewer, which means you're copying junk.

Problem 3: You're not adding a null terminator to `second_arr`.

Just do this:

```
if (scanf("%255s", string) != 1)
{
    printf("scanf failed\n");
    return 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < 256 && string[i]; i++) {
    if(string[i]=='('||string[i]=='['||string[i]=='{'){
        second_arr[j]=string[i];
        j++;
    }
}
second_arr[j] = '\0';
printf("%s", second_arr);
return 0;
```

Comment: `scanf` can also return a non-EOF value on failure

Comment: @MattMcNabb True. My suggested code handles that but I edited my answer to reflect your point. Thanks!

Comment: The `i < 256` test seems unnecessary, since if `scanf` was successful, it will have deposited a `NUL` terminated string in `string`, so the `string[i]` test should suffice.  If the bounds test is trying to prevent `second_arr` from overflowing, then the test should have been `j < 255`.

Comment: @pat Good point, and checking `j` isn't strictly necessary either since the format string will prevent overflow. Depends on how defensive you want to be. Someone could easily change the format string without noticing it was a crucial limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (i=0; string[i]!=0; i++) // iterate the input string until the null-character
{
    if (string[i] == '(' || string[i] == '[' || string[i] == '{')
        second_arr[j++] = string[i];
}
second_arr[j] = 0; // set a null-character at the end of the output string
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to terminate the second string. Add

```
||string[i]=='\0'
```

to your conditions. Also break out of the loop when you see that null char, but only after you have copied it.

Comment: I keep forgeting about terminating the string for some reasons. =(

Answer (score -1):

You should add at the end of second string `second_arr` the char `'\n'` to indicate its end.